Is there a Bokeh equivalent to Matplotlib's `useOffset` for offset in axis tick labels?
Plotting points whose y-coordinates' average value is very large but whose variance is small, the labels on the y-axis are not useful. Either one can use high precision custom format--whereupon the number is exceedingly long--or one can use low-precision format, but then you can't see the difference between the labels on the ticks.
In Matplotlib, there's a useOffset option for label formatting (default is True) which adds a +N above the axis where N indicates the large approximate average offset of the values. It picks a number N that yields nicer (as in, more round) numbers for tick labels. Then the tick labels are concise yet display the range of the data values to full precision. See Maptlotlib docs for useOffset.
Some examples with and without the useOffset option can be found in Matplotlib's plot gallery.
I expect I can formulate elaborate-enough code to achieve something like this in Bokeh, too, but I was wondering if there's something more simple built-in to Bokeh (I can't find it in docs or with a web search). If there isn't anything built-in, I'll post the code I come up with to achieve something similar.
One can replicate the Bokeh results I'm getting in JupyterLab via
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show

output_notebook()

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1001)

fig = figure()
fig.line(x=t, y=1e8 + np.sin(t))
show(fig)


All y-tick labels are the same ("1.000e+8"), so one cannot tell the amplitude of the sinusoid. Meanwhile, Matplotlib produces, for the same data,
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1001)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, 1e8 + np.sin(t))


y-axis tick labels "-1.00, -0.75, ..., 0.75, 1.00" and places "+1e8" above the axis. Both the scale of the offset and the amplitude of the sinusoid are clearly and concisely communicated.

Nothing built-in specifically for this, but there is CustomJSTickFormatter which affords you complete control over exactly how ticks are formatted.
